# How to adjust background image in mobile for wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, css, media-queries

I am using the Tesseract theme from tyler.com and I am using the visual editor to set a fill background image. The background image seems to look ok in desktop, but mobile seems to not be scalong properly. http://kingsmanarms.us is the website. Should I use a class and media queries to target different devices? I read something about -webkit. Please help

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should media query, and your background attachment should be fixed, try this and in your mobile the background will be good to look :) since your div has set to static we should use '!important' for this.

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) { 
.panel-row-style {
        background-size: inherit !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathew Paule! It worked eliminating the blurry look but the background image doesn't scale in height. I'm thinking it has to do with the way the background image is placed in the row and the row having multiple visual editors